# Toggle wireframe mode with hotkey

Tags: shortcut

How do I toggle in and out of wireframe mode with my keyboard? Is there a hotkey for this?

I'm a beginner (obviously). I thought I could find this in the "view" menu, but it either doesn't exist or I have horrendous eyesight. Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In any mode, if you want to switch between wireframe and solid use <kbd>Z</kbd>.
You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for toggling x-ray.

Alternatively, you can use the viewport header.

Take a look at the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/editors/3dview/display/shading.html).

Comment: Also to note that "SHIFT+Z", to switch between rendered and solid, only works since Blender 2.69 (AFAIK)

Comment: Updated manual link: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html

Comment: How do I show both wireframe and solid at the same time?

Comment: @AaronFranke sadly you cannot do that directly in the viewport. But you still can show the wire one object while you're in solide mode:
Properties pannel --> Object properties --> Display --> tick 'Wire'

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to toggle the Object Properties > Viewport Display > (Show) Wireframe checkbox (as seen in a video).
Didn't find the answer here, but I figured out (in Blender 3.2.2): right-click on the property name > Add Shortcut. Later we can Change Shortcut or Remove Shortcut.
The main issue is to find a key not already used by default by Blender… the video used ';' but it is already used in 3.2 for Transform Pivot Point. I chose '<'.

Answer (score -6):

First select the concerned objects and Press 4 to go to wireframe mode. Press 5 to get out of it.

Comment: If you mean 4 on main keyboard, it will move selected object to 4th 3D layer. If you mean Numpad 4 then it will rotate the view around Z axis in the viewport. I don't have an idea where is wireframe mode related here

Comment: The Z key toggles between Wireframe and Solid view in the viewport window. Shift-Z toggles between Render view and Wireframe view.