# Black wires covering object

Tags: smoke-simulation, wireframe

Im quite bloody inexperienced in this software, so you might as well call me a noob, but here is my problem:

I was modelling a soda can, then I decided to make a stand for it and accidentally pressed the smoke simulation. Afterwards I don't know what I pressed when suddenly the can and the stand turned black with bazillion of wires.

What I know is that I put a lot of Edge Loops as a finishing touch for the can before it happened and it has subsurf modifier on it.

Heres a picture:

[image]

Soooo, basically I'm stuck at this point (School Project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle wireframe mode with hotkey](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/toggle-wireframe-mode-with-hotkey)

Comment: Not sure what happened but maybe your pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+## (some nunber key) and that automatically adds a subsurf modifier to your object, making it a densely packed mesh.
Can you show a screenshot of your modifier stack?

Comment: @someonewithpc the image shows solid shading, not wireframe

Comment: @NoobyUser can you upload your file? You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the resulting link into your question.

Comment: @NoobyUser didn't any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Enabling a smoke simulation changes the maximum draw type to "wire", as opposed to the default "textured".

[image: Wire]

I believe what you are looking for is this:

[image]

EDIT: This is in the object tab in the properties panel. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Just push 'Z' to toggle wireframe mode.

Comment: You can see from their toolbar that they are in solid mode.