# Solid Wireframe, F4 shortcut

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, wireframe, object-mode

I'm new to Blender - and to any 3D modelling software, really - so I started following tutorials on Youtube. In this particular case, the OP says to toggle the wireframe on the solid interface by pressing F4. Here's the link to the video, and go to minute 18:50:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYUK5HantuE&list=PLxt9ZAGPLIpcuPkSTGOJ9iZssTG3o1a0p&index=4

If I press F4, a simple contextual menu opens up:

[image]

but this should be the result:

[image]

I checked the key shortcuts in settings, but F4 is nowhere to be found in relation to wireframe:

[image]

I'm running Blender 2.91.2 on a M1 Mac.

Thanks in advance to whoever can solve this mystery to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle wireframe mode with hotkey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/toggle-wireframe-mode-with-hotkey)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He simply toggles Wireframe.
It's in the *Overlays* menu, but doesn't have a shortcut by default.

(You can assign a custom shortcut by right-clicking on the checkbox > Assign Shortcut.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

F4 for seeing the wireframe is not by default like that. I have added the F4 shortcut to see wireframe.

- Removal of default F4

First you need to remove the current short-cut associated with F4 by going to the preference menu. Edit=>Preference=>Keymap.  Go to keybinding and type in F4 to see what is by default linked to F4.  Deselect the box on the left.

- Adding new F4 for wireframe

Click on viewport overlays.
Right click over the box next to wireframe.
Click on assign shortcut key and press F4.