# How to quit outer edge only wireframe

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, wireframe

I somehow managed to get wireframe looked like this:

[image]

How to change it back to default wireframe view?

Edit: here is the sample file. [image]

Comment: I don't have an issue with your file, so seem s like graphic card issue, check the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle X-Ray on top row of 3DView Editor.

[image]

Or check [JachymMichal's answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/209580/2214).

Comment: It does not solve my issue, I still can't see an "x ray" in wireframe, unless I go to the edit mode.

Comment: OK. Please attach your simplified blend file (it can be a Cube) to see your setup. Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and paste given code into your question by click on "edit" at bottom of your Q).